How to create new database view using SQL code
I want to build a function called create_db_view_arr_tdt in the main agent to create a new database view database_view_arr_tdt and sort it according to an existing column tdt in the database arrivals.
I already created the database view manually and this is the SQL code I use to sort the database view:
SELECT 
    *

FROM 
    arrivals

ORDER BY
    tdt;

I want to run the code before each simulation run in the section "Before simulation run:" root.create_db_view_arr_tdt();. Therefore the existing database view called database_view_arr_tdt should be deleted and a new one should be created.

Does anybode know how i can delete the existing database view database_view_arr_tdt and create a new one with the same name and sort it with the SQL code from above?
Many thanks for your help.
Best regards.

You can execute any SQL statement via code using executeStatement("my cool SQL statement to run");
So just research how to create view in SQL and call the function above.
For example:
executeStatement("
CREATE VIEW view_customers AS
SELECT CustomerName, ContactName
FROM Customers
WHERE Country = 'Brazil';");

